# Composing a likelihood function for a convolved normal- and lognormal- dataset

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, lognormal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am trying to use some implementation of MLE to solve for the parameters of a mixed normal and lognormal population, and have had no end of trouble.  A colleague and the internet has me convinced that `optim()` (R) can do what I need, but maybe not.

Simply put, I have a population that whose “value” is log-normally distributed, but there is an additive and normally distributed “error” (think of it as measurement uncertainty/limit of detection) convolved in the sample.  With a log-normal population that spans many decades and an additive, linear noise that is small by comparison, the small values in my final population are dominated by the “error” distribution, and the large values are dominated by the “value” distribution.  Synthetic data is as follows (req: ggplot):

```
# data generation
data <- log(exp(rnorm(1000000,15,10))+rnorm(1000000,100,200))
data <- data[!is.na(data)]
thing <- hist(data, breaks=3000, plot=F)
thingout <- data.frame(bin=thing$mids, count=thing$counts)

ggplot(thingout) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=exp(bin), y=count), alpha=.25) + 
  scale_x_log10() + annotation_logticks(sides="b")

# latest iteration of my -log likelihood attempt.  NOTE: equations 
# are for simple gaussians, not NORMAL gaussians (absent the scalar).
mixed.lik <- function(theta,y) {
  logmu <- theta[1]
  logsig <- theta[2]
  linmu <- (theta[3])
  linsig <- (theta[4])
  y <- y[!is.na(log(y))]
  n <- length(y)
  logl <- -2*n-(1/(2*logsig^2))*sum((log(y)-logmu)^2) - 
           log((1/(2*linsig^2))*sum((y-linmu)^2))
  return(-logl)
}

mlething <- optim(c(14, 11, 110, 220), mixed.lik, y=data, method="BFGS")
mlething$pars
```

as is clearly seen, my theta values are nothing like they should be (i.e. 15, 10, 100, 200).  I imagine there are many points at which I could be screwing this up… in exponentiating and then re-log-ing the sample data, in believing my theta values are the same that i used to generate the data (and not log(lin.mu) or exp(mu+sig^2) or something), in thinking that I can just drop the scalar portion of the gaussian’s (and hence likelihood functions), etc.  Trying to keep track of which parts/objects are log and which are linear has got my head a little inside-out, and I’ve tried so many iterations of this that I’m verifiably stumped.

I had previously tried to derive a PDF for the combined distribution for use in `nls()`, but didn't have the knowledge to finish the convolution... if that would be an easier path, I'm open to it.